# Narrow Down Union Type Typescipt

Tags: typescript

In here I want to narrow down union types based on the type of a key of a union objects type, below I have an example to explain more.

```
type Foo = {
   name: 'foo';
   lable: 'A Foo';
};

type Bar = {
   name: 'bar';
   lable: 'A Bar';
};

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

type FilterLabel<N extends FooBar['name']> = FooBar['label'] // Here I want to get label value ex. FilterLabel<'bar'> then return should be `A Bar`
```

Answer (score 2):

your last line is not very clear... but you actually don't need much. Typescript will help you. For exemple :

```
type Foo = {
   name: 'foo';
   lable: 'A Foo';
};

type Bar = {
   name: 'bar';
   lable: 'A Bar';
};

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

const someFunction = (fooBar: FooBar) => {
  if (fooBar.name === 'foo') {
    // here fooBar is of type Foo
  } else {
    // here fooBar is of type Bar
  }
}
```